# javascript manual click on target to send event in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I use in iOS UIwebView that caught events from javascript code. I detect commands are sent by click:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    NSString *urlStr = request.URL.absoluteString;
    if ([urlStr rangeOfString:@"close"].location == 0) {
        [self.delegate fullScreenBannerControllerOnClose:self];
    } else if ([urlStr rangeOfString:COMMAND_KEY].location == 0) {
        [[Market instance] executeCommand:banner.command]
    } else if ([urlStr rangeOfString:@"get_prices"].location == 0) {
        [[Shop instance] loadProducts];
    } 
    return NO; 
}
return YES;
}
```

All fine when user click on html banner. But now I need invoke command manual

I use in html:

```
<a href="get_prices://" id="price_id" ></a>
```

And on load invoke function

```
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload="getPrices()">
```

And this function do manual click

```
function getPrices() {
    document.getElementById("price_id").click();
};
```

But I get command:

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/F4DB923C-27D4-4677-B0DA-C7F0713E5D20/Library/content/dynamic/get_prices://
```

And my code wait that `get_prices` will be on the beginning of string, but it in the end. How can I resolve this problem and manual send click command `get_prices` to my UIWebView

Comment: This may help... if([urlStr rangeOfString: @"get_prices://"].location != NSNotFound)

Comment: I forget to say, that app in release and I must fing solution with JS

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to solve your issue by javascript only.